# Virtual Ip(private one)

Tags: ip-address, virtual-machine, vmware, mongrel

I have a private ip and a vmSphere account credentials.
I can login from a windows system with vSphere using ip,usename,password and it gives RemoteDesktop of a centos server.There i configured a Rails server and i am getting appropriage page when I am giving `http://localhost:3000`

When i try to ping to that ipaddress from windows it is working,But can't access the ruby server when i am trying ipaddress:3000 through browser.Remember the IP is a private range ip-address

When i am trying the ip(172.16.XX.XX) with browser I am not getting the Apache page.but it is giving a VmWare home page.I don't know about these virtual ip things.I can ping to the same ip from that system only since it is a private ip. But not giving the ruby server.

Comment: Is that private-IP address on the same network as you? Remember, since it's a private IP, it cannot pass through any routers, as they'll drop the private IP packets on the floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your server process is starting up bound to `0.0.0.0:3000` and not `127.0.0.1:3000` which is local only. One way to test this is by trying using your host name or IP, for example, `http://192.168.X.X:3000/` where `192.168.X.X` is your server's IP.

If you're going to be using this on systems other than your own, you may want to use either [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) or [Pow](http://pow.cx/) to launch your application. Mongrel is limited in what it can do in a stand-alone capacity.

Comment: The ip is like 172.16.1*.** .That is a vmware ip.I can login to that ip with some credentials.But can't access even the apache server from there.It is going to some vmWare page.